# Grunt-sass Segmentation fault: 11 Error

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, gruntjs

I'm getting a Segmentation fault 11 error when building CSS files from Sass files using grunt-sass. The Grunt-sass process build 5 (out of 15) CSS files then gives Segmentation fault: 11 and stops. I've updated Node and npm to latest versions but no luck. But I'm not sure if this is a Grunt, Grunt-sass issue or Node issue. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting `node_modules` and doing a fresh `npm install` removed the error.

Answer found here: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1107#issuecomment-134872295